# 100 mathematicians each have a numbers written on their foreheads

Tags: puzzle

100 mathematicians each have a number written on their foreheads, visible to all but themself. One day, a meta-mathematician comes by and remarks, "I see all the numbers are distinct natural numbers." She then proceeds to repeatedly ask them the question:

> Do you know where your number ranks among your peers?

And each time, the mathematicians have to truthfully answer yes or no simultaneously. There's no other communication.

In the worst case scenario, how many mathematicians will always remain uncertain about their ranks, saying no forever?

Comment: In the case where the numbers are exactly $0,\ldots 99$, the person with $99$ can infer they are ranked highest in the very first round, and all others can directly infer from this that the numbers $0,\ldots,98$ are all taken, and hence know their number in the second round. Are there any other cases in which *anyone* can infer anything? For example, if the number $0$ isn't taken, I think no one can ever distinguish between having the number $0$ or a number higher than everyone else, hence no one ever says anything, but I might be missing something.

Comment: @AchimKrause For example, if the numbers are 1~100, then 100 can't be sure if they are 0 or something higher than everyone else before the first round. But after the first round, they know they can't be 0, because if they were, 99 would have said yes in the first round.

Comment: Ah, good point! I missed that no one saying anything in the first round can also generate information.